# Why does this work? SQL, ExactTarget

Tags: sql, exacttarget

I'm using the following query in ExactTarget and wondering why I need to use the table name in the GROUP BY statement but not in the WHERE statement.

```
SELECT _Open.SubscriberKey, MIN(_Open.EventDate) AS EventDate3

FROM _Open
INNER JOIN _Job
ON _Open.JobID = _Job.JobID

WHERE EmailID = 10339639

GROUP BY _Open.SubscriberKey
```

It works fine, just wondering why/when the table name is needed in front of the column name and when it is not.

Answer (score 2):

If field is unique to table then you don't need table name.
SubscriberKey is only present in one table, so you can either say

```
SubscriberKey or _open.Subscriberkey (optional)
```

But if field is present in more than 1 tables ,so you need to specify which table to use. example JobID is  present in 2 tables, so you have to specify which table
 `(jobs.JobID or _open.JobID)`

This convention has nothing to do with where clause or group by query.

Comment: So since SubscriberKey and EventDate are unique to the _Open table, i could write the query like this..? SELECT SubscriberKey, MIN(EventDate) AS EventDate1

FROM _Open
INNER JOIN _Job
ON _Open.JobID = _Job.JobID

WHERE EmailID = 10339638

GROUP BY SubscriberKey